# ASP.NET Formview Item Inserting Event

Tags: asp.net, sql, formview

I'm using the FormView control in ASP.NET for a simple form to insert into a MS SQL DB. I have an event for onItemInserting to set some values behind (such as time stamp, etc) and was curious how to check some user entered values in the onItemInserting event and **cancel** the item from being inserted. The reason I want to do it in the code behind is to query the database and use the values to validate the user entered data.

Pseudo Code is as follows:

```
protected void Form_addRoom_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
  ... Query DB for some values ...
  if(enteredMaxPeople > queryMaxPeople)
  {
    **Cancel** DB Insert
    statusLabel.text = "Value entered not valid";
  }
}
```

In the end the question comes down to how do I cancel a FormView from inserting in the code behind?

Thank you!
Sean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
e.Cancel = true;
```